# Encrypting Mysql database stored files on disk

Tags: mysql, encryption, database

Is it possible for Mysql to encrypt its stored files (database scheme & data on disk) in a way that someone not be able to copy these files to another machine that and read them using his own installed Mysql `root` user?
if not is there a DBMS that be able to protect database stored files on disk by encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support data file encryption natively.

However, there are 3rd products out there like:

http://www.vormetric.com/products/vormetric_database_encryption_expert.html

To be honest, if the database content has any commercial value or contains personal data about individuals, you should really control who has access to the datafiles (whether encrypted or not).

Comment: Thanks, What about other DBMS? is there one with support of data file encryption ?

Answer (score 1):

To use the windows EFS encryption:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/encrypt-decrypt-folder-file#1TC=windows-7

Read more obout it:

http://www.petri.co.il/how_does_efs_work.htm#

!!! Don't forget to export the certificate !!!

If you are using windows EFS and starting MySQL as a service, you will need to do the following:

- go to Services and find the MySQL service
- stop the service
- right-click -> properties -> LogON TAB
- check "This account"
- fill your windows account name eg. ".\username"
- provide your password
- start the service

The MySQL service should now start without errors.